# Duration Viterbi Algorithm

Tags: ai.artificial-intel, dynamic-programming, markov-chains

I am searching for some good resources to understand the Duration Viterbi algorithm.

Does anyone knows a good resource to understand and learn how to model a Duration Viterbi Hidden Markov Chain Model ?

The algorithm is based on the Viterbi one, but the transition model consider also the duration of each state.

Comment: link to algorithm description ?

Comment: the only paper I found so far is http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V18-3YSXP9V-R&_user=607013&_coverDate=01%2F31%2F1995&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_acct=C000031523&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=607013&md5=13ad7f413ad7421fc269573bcbe28535&searchtype=a

Comment: Google "duration hidden Markov model" without the quotes...there are tons of relevant results, including the one you mentioned. In particular: http://www.hisashikobayashi.com/papers/Hidden%20Semi%20Markov%20Model%20(HSMM)%20and%20Computational%20Algorithms/An%20Efficient%20Forward-Backward%20Algorithm%20for%20an%20Explicit%20Duration%20Hidden%20Markov%20Model.pdf . It may not be the Viterbi algorithm, but it looked reasonable to me (though I only glanced at it for about a second).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best resource to understand how to model state duration in HMM, that I found is  [Rabiner's tutorial on hidden markov models](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/rabiner.pdf).

Section D: Inclusion of Explicit State Duration Density in HMM.